# Multidimensional array - how to get a value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following very massive array:

```
var arrayBig = {"count":31,"items":{"76":{"title":"office1","address":"<p><strong>London<\/strong><\/p>\r\n<p>Baker Str.<\/p>\r\n<p>Web site: <a href=\"http:\/\/example.org\">http:\/\/example.org<\/a><\/p>"},"57":{"title":....... etc. }....
```

And all I need is to get the first number in 'items', e.g. 76, with jQuery.

Comment: It's not an array. To access object attributes use `.` or `[]` operators.

Comment: You can get it with [object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method of JS.

Comment: @Alexander Arutinyants: it worth mentioning that properties of objects are not ordered. And the standard **DOES NOT** guarantee any order. So technically - it's impossible to retrieve the **first** attribute of an object.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to get 'title' or 'address'. But don't know how to get the number in the beginning - it has no name.

Comment: Ok. I see, first you wanna do search by any field, then get the number?

Comment: I want to make a loop. And get all the values - as well as 'title' and 'address', but also the id.

Comment: for(key in arrayBig.items){
    if(arrayBig.items[key].title === "office1"){ //use this condition to search
    console.log(key);
    break; //important to not to scan all array        
    }
};

othervise just loop and console log key, arrayBig.items[key].title and arrayBig.items[key].addr

Comment: I made a jsfiddle for you where you can play with all this: http://jsfiddle.net/elennaro/7ht9prh0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var arrayObj = [];
    $.each(arrayBig.items, function(key, val) {

           arrayObj.push(key);

        });​

alert(arrayObj[0]);
```

Comment: How does this code take only the first value?

Comment: store all values in array and take array[0]....simple.

Comment: You're not doing either of those in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
var firstKey = Object.keys(arrayBig.items)[0];
arrayBig.items[firstKey]
```

Comment: Order of properties **IS NOT DEFINED** and **IS NOT GUARANTEED**.

Comment: @zerkms it returns first key anyway. If it should be the lowest key in group, array of keys should be sorted.

Comment: "it returns first key anyway" --- it returns for this particular run for this particular version of ECMAScript implementation. Nothing prevents the JS VM to change the object layout for memory optimization purposes. It's like crazy to rely on something that is not standardized and is not guaranteed.